# Application name different from icon label

Tags: android

Is it possible to have an application name that is different from the label displayed under the icon?
I have an app that has a long name and I want to use an acronym for the label under the icon, but for the label only. On Google Play, and everywhere else, I want the full name to be displayed.
For instance the name would be "Special Weapons And Tactics" and the label "SWAT".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload it on the Developer Console, you pick the Google Play display name there, it doesn't read it from your application. So whatever you pick as the `android:label` attribute for each Activity will be what is displayed as the label under the launcher icon. You can pick whatever you want as the title on Google Play, though.